# Increasing or decreasing integral

Tags: integration, functions

I need to check whether the following expression is increasing or decreasing :

$$F(\beta)=\dfrac{\int_0^{0.5}t^2(1-t)^{\beta-1}dt}{\int_0^1t^2(1-t)^{\beta-1}dt}$$

where $\beta$ varies over all real numbers. I tried to compare $F(\beta)$ and $F(\gamma)$ for $\beta>\gamma$. But then $(1-t)^{\beta-1}<(1-t)^{\gamma-1}$ for $\beta >\gamma>1$. This approach doesn't seem to enlighten my path to a conclusion. I seek help regarding any other possible approaches.

Comment: This is a regularized incomplete Beta integral.

Comment: ok. So is there any standard result on its monotonicity.

Comment: http://statipedia.org/wiki/images/a/a5/325px-Beta_distribution_cdf.png

Answer (score 1):

Notice:

- $$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}t^2\left(1-t\right)^{\beta-1}\space\text{d}t=\frac{2^{-2-\beta}\left(2^{3+\beta}-\beta^2-5\beta-8\right)}{\beta(1+\beta)(2+\beta)}$$
- $$\int_{0}^{1}t^2\left(1-t\right)^{\beta-1}\space\text{d}t=\frac{2\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(3+\beta)}\space\text{ when }\space\Re(b)>0$$

So:

$$\frac{\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}t^2\left(1-t\right)^{\beta-1}\space\text{d}t}{\int_{0}^{1}t^2\left(1-t\right)^{\beta-1}\space\text{d}t}=1-2^{-3-\beta}(8+\beta(5+\beta))\space\text{ when }\space\Re(b)>0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int t^2(1-t)^{\beta-1}\text dt=\int (1-t)^{\beta+1}\text dt-2\int (1-t)^{\beta}\text dt+\int(1-t)^{\beta -1}\text dt\\
=-\frac 1{\beta+2}(1-t)^{\beta+2}+\frac 2{\beta+1}(1-t)^{\beta+1}-\frac 1\beta(1-t)^\beta$$

With evaluation, we have

$${\left.\frac 1{\beta+2}(1-t)^{\beta+2}-\frac 2{\beta+1}(1-t)^{\beta+1}+\frac 1\beta(1-t)^\beta\right|_0^{0.5}\over \left.\frac 1{\beta+2}(1-t)^{\beta+2}-\frac 2{\beta+1}(1-t)+\frac 1\beta(1-t)^\beta\right|_0^1}={\frac 1{2^\beta}\left(\frac 1{4(\beta+2)}-\frac 1{\beta+1}+\frac 1\beta\right)-\frac 1{\beta+2}+\frac 2{\beta+1}-\frac 1\beta\over -\frac 1{\beta+2}+\frac 2{\beta+1}-\frac 1\beta}\\
=1-{8+5\beta+\beta^2\over 2^{\beta+3}}$$

This does not appear to be monotone over real numbers $\beta$, having zeroes at $\beta=-2,-1, 0$.